# Automatically replace text in Excel on a column by column basis

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a few hundred columns in Excel and each column has random "x" in some cells, and all other cells are empty.  At the top of each column is a specific ID number.  I need to replace each "x" in the column with the ID number at the top of it's column.

I tried `=SUBSTITUTE(F4,"x",F2)` and various iterations, and that doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm an excel newbie, so thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using this macro

```
Sub RepX()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim xCell As Range, Area As Range
    
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Area = WS.Range("A1:E10") 'Replace with your range
    For Each xCell In Area.Cells
        If xCell.Value = "x" Then
           xCell.Value = WS.Cells(1, xCell.Column) '1 is for row number. Replace with row number where your TOP IDs are.
           
        End If
        Next xCell
        
End Sub
```

What it does:

[image]

[image]

---

To add a macro just press `ALT+F11` and it the left panel right click and `Insert > Module`. Paste the code above in that window and click the RUN ► icon.

---

**[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/df42by/if_cell_contains_specific_text_replace_with_value/)**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all columns are adjacent and data you want to transform starts in column `A` as in @User552853 example, an approach that does not require VBA is using this formula:

```
=IF(A2="X",A$1,"")
```

This formula would be best placed at **the far right end** of the contiguous columns that you want to replace, and then copy to the right as well as down for as many cells as needed.

Once you are happy that the new data is how you want it, you can copy the range containing the new data and paste it in the same place as values, then delete the original columns.

Adjust as needed `A2` and `A$1` in the formula to reflect where the first data cell and the headings are, respectively.

To copy headings, just use `=A1` for the first one and then copy to the right. Adjust as needed.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: For some reason I get the circular reference argument when trying this and my cells just show "0".  I took a screenshot showing my output, but I can't post it in this little comment section.  I did this =IF(A3="x",A$1,"") I'm on a mac, so not sure if that has something to do with it.

Comment: @Joel in which cell did you put the formula `=IF(A3="x",A$1,"")` ?

Comment: in A3-which explains the feedback loop, but don't i need it pointing to itself-otherwise it will try and put the number in a different cell?

Comment: @Joel _don't i need it pointing to itself_ No. That's why you were getting 'Circular reference' errors. _otherwise it will try and put the number in a different cell?_ Yes, that is the approach suggested (check the screenshot). The steps are 1) add formulas to the right of original data 2) copy the formulas you just created and paste values _in the same place_ where they are. Now you have the data you want albeit sitting to the right of your original data. 3) When you're happy that everything looks good, delete the original columns and you'll be left with the end-result only.

Comment: @Joel if you prefer an approach that replaces the original cells directly without duplicating the columns first, then the macro solution by User552853 is the way to go.